# React component second time render issue

Tags: reactjs, components

I am building a tasks board app and I have an issue with rendering the TasksList component within a board of 3 lists: 1 Board -> 3 lists -> N tasks

It seems like the TasksList component is being rendered twice, which is fine, but on the 2nd time it seems to return different values for each task (which are wrong according to my conditional return, and right on the first render - why would there be a difference?)

I also get this warning. Maybe ts related:
Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.

Board.js component render function:

```
const tasksListsArr = Object.entries(this.state.tasks).map(list => {
            return (
                <TasksList
                    key={list[0]}
                    listrole={list[0]}
                    listTitle={this.state.Lists[list[0]]}
                    tasks={list[1]}
                    listTextChangedHandler={event => this.listTextChangedHandler(list[0], event)}
                    addTaskHandler={() => this.addTaskHandler(list[0])}
                    taskDeleteHandler={this.taskDeleteHandler}
                    moveTaskHandler={this.moveTaskHandler}
                    taskEditHandler={this.taskEditHandler}
                    taskEditApprove={this.taskEditApprove}
                />
            )
        })
```

TaskList.js component:

```
import React from "react"
import classes from "./TasksList.module.css"

const TasksList = props => {
    const tasks = props.tasks.map(task => {
        const buttonLeft =
            !task.isEdit && (props.listrole === "inprogress" || props.listrole === "done") ? (
                <button onClick={() => props.moveTaskHandler(task.id, "left")}>left</button>
            ) : null

        const buttonRight =
            !task.isEdit && (props.listrole === "inprogress" || props.listrole === "backlog") ? (
                <button onClick={() => props.moveTaskHandler(task.id, "right")}>right</button>
            ) : null

        const taskUtils = task.isEdit ? null : (
            <div>
                <span onClick={() => props.taskDeleteHandler(props.listrole, task.id)}>X</span>
                <span onClick={() => props.taskEditHandler(props.listrole, task.id)}>edit</span>
            </div>
        )

        const taskContent = task.isEdit ? (
            <div>
                <input
                    type='text'
                    onChange={event => props.listTextChangedHandler(props.listrole, event)}
                />
                <button onClick={props.taskEditApprove(props.listrole, task.id)}>OK</button>
            </div>
        ) : (
            <div>
                <div>{task.text}</div>
            </div>
        )

        return (
            <div key={task.id} className={classes.Task}>
                {buttonLeft}
                {taskContent}
                {buttonRight}
                {taskUtils}
            </div>
        )
    })
    console.log(tasks)

    return (
        <div className={classes.List}>
            <h2 className={classes.ListTitle}> {props.listTitle} </h2>
            <input type='text' onChange={props.listTextChangedHandler} placeholder='Add task...' />
            <button onClick={props.addTaskHandler}>+</button>
            <div className={classes.TasksList}>{tasks}</div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

export default TasksList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the issue is in TaskList component. Because the onChange of input and onClick of button getting called on every render but those event handler functions should be called only when user integrated with it. So to fix change them to arrow way so that the function gets called only when we interact.

Following changes required in TaskList.js

Change

```
     <button onClick={props.taskEditApprove(props.listrole, task.id)}>OK</button>
```

To

```
    <button onClick={() => props.taskEditApprove(props.listrole, task.id)}>OK</button>
```

And

Change

```
    <input type='text' onChange={props.listTextChangedHandler} placeholder='Add task...' />
        <button onClick={props.addTaskHandler}>+. </button>
```

To

```
    <input type='text' onChange={event => props.listTextChangedHandler(event)} placeholder='Add task...' />
        <button onClick={() => props.addTaskHandler()}>+</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK

props.taskEditApprove is being called in render.

Try
 props.taskEditApprove(props.listrole, task.id)}>OK

Then function will be called only on interaction.